# I'm using git, and just git init a workspace and never commit, but the .gitignore is not working

Tags: git, rules, gitignore

I have a project dir, and I `git init` the dir. Then I created a `.gitignore` file in the same dir, and copied these[.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) rules

```
# OS generated files #
.DS_Store
# SVN control files #
.svn
```

and then I tried `git add`, and the console outputs:

```
add '.DS_Store'
add '.gitignore'
add '.svn/all-wcprops'
add '.svn/entries'
```

the `.gitignore` seems not working. Can someone help me?

### Add:

a lot of similar questions says that, use "git rm -r --cached ." But i have never commit once, it just dont helpful!

As you wish, here is git status output:

```
by-01-0497:trunck appleofuestc$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store
#   .gitignore
#   .svn/
#   SiChuan-Mahjong/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Can you run `git status` and add the output to your question please?

Comment: It sounds like you added .DS_Store to your .gitignore and *then* ran a git add '.DS_Store'. You should have then received the following error "The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files" what version of git are you running?

Comment: preinstalled git in 10.8.4, version 1.7.12.4

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the `.gitignore` in the same folder as your `.git` folder.
Or you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451916/1305081).

Comment: i have said that " I created a .gitignore file in the same dir"