# Git want me to add ignored files to stage. Why?

Tags: git

I've created `.gitignore` file to ignore eclipse files, it looks like this:

```
target
.classpath
.project
.settings/
```

The problem is that git status still shows me that those files can be added to stage:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .classpath
#       .project
#       .settings/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Any idea why? BTW I'm new git user, I work on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you've added them to your `.gitignore`, sometimes Git will not ignore them once it already *knows* about them. You can fix it by executing these:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Ignore eclipse files"
```

Comment: After calling `git add .`, command `git status` is showing that ignored files has been added to stage. Is it ok?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you writing your `.gitignore` file using Notepad by chance?

Comment: Yes. The problem may occurs because of windows style new lines?

Comment: Yes, I do believe so. Try saving it in another text editor such as Notepad++, or saving it specifically using ANSI encoding in Notepad. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451916/2446208) may be useful for you.

Comment: Problem finally solved. It was really stupid mistake :) I created my files not with notepad but from windows command line using `echo` command, for example `echo .classpath >> .gitignore`. And where is the problem? SPACE between `.classpath` and `>>`. I didn't see that these spaces were added to `.gitignore` at the end of each line. I've also changed line endings to unix style. @caseyscarborough you helped me a lot!

Comment: Very interesting problem! Glad you got it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the same mistake as me and @pepuch with `echo ignoreme >> .gitignore`, and this time with powershell, it's possible for the encoding to be incorrect also (mine was set to `UTF-16BOM` according to notepad++), so make sure that it uses `UTF-8`.