# .gitignore Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore:

```
.DS_Store
/.idea
/.idea_modules
/out
/project
/target
/*.iml
*/resolution-cache/*
*/streams/*
*/target/*
```

But nonetheless, the folders `.idea`, `.idea_modules` and `target` have appeared in a repo and are still there.

Your ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring is only useful for files that are not currently being tracked by the repo. If those directories were added to the repo before being put in .gitignore, they will continue to be tracked.

Use `git rm --cached <file>` to stop tracking a file.

Of course you should make a commit with the removed files and push to the repo to see the changes in the remote repository

Comment: If I want to remove a whole folder, what's the format for that: `git rm --cached target` or `git rm --cached  /target` or anything else?

Comment: To remove a whole folder, remove recursively `git rm --cached -r target`.