# directory in .gitignore is not deleted from repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to delete a directory `venv` (Virtual Environment) from **BitBucket** repository. I've added an entry for `venv/` into `.gitignore` file but the `venv` was uploaded during first commit to repository.

In  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository), author says that I have to clean cache.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit
```

.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

So I looked into **BitBucket** account and I still see `venv` directory and files inside it.

```
git status --ignored
```

returns this:

```
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        venv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/t32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/t64.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/w32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/w64.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/cli-32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/cli-64.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/cli-arm-32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/cli.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/gui-32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/gui-64.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/gui-arm-32.exe
        venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/gui.exe
        venv/Scripts/django-admin.exe
        venv/Scripts/easy_install-2.7.exe
        venv/Scripts/easy_install.exe
        venv/Scripts/pip.exe
        venv/Scripts/pip2.7.exe
        venv/Scripts/pip2.exe
        venv/Scripts/python.exe
        venv/Scripts/pythonw.exe
        venv/Scripts/wheel.exe

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I've find out that some files are not there. For example `django-admin.exe` but why there are still other files?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974914/gitignore-doesnt-seem-to-work. Adding a file to .gitignore does not retroactively remove it from the repository. You have to use `git rm --cached` for that.

Comment: Did you push to Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
git rm -r --cached venv
echo venv/>.gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "Remove venv tracked content and ignores it"
git push
```

Then you would not see anymore venv on the remote BitBucket repo.

If your `.gitignore` was *already* ignoring the `venv/` folder content, check that it is still the case with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- venv/aFile
```