# git checkout . not working on R.java

Tags: android, git, r.java-file, posh-git

I am working on an android project through Github. Now, when I pull any commit and do any unwanted changes in working directory, I use git checkout . to revert back. This works fine with all other files but shows R.java still as modified. How to revert R.java file also? I am using PowerShell Git in Windows8.

Comment: you shouldn't be adding R.java to source control, as it is a generated file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.java` is automatically generated and shouldn't be checked into VCS. You have to add the following lines to your `.gitignore` file to prevent generated files to be added to the source control:

```
# Generated files
bin/
gen/
```

Comment: Thanks, but alongwith this, I had to use "git rm . -r --cached" as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working , to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The .gitignore file that covers the current directory may have a *.java exclusion in it. You can include these files if you remove these definitions from .gitignore