# Why does Eclipse ignore gitignore?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

This is rather weird because even before I made my first commit to the remote repository, I made sure that my `gitignore` was all set and ready. My gitignore for my Android project looks like this:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log
```

However, when I did
Right Click - Team - Remote - Push,  everything got pushed to the remote repository. Which is strange.
**What have I done wrong?**

Comment: How did you create `.gitignore`? Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451916/1889459) and see if it helps.

Comment: .gitignore only controls which files show up as untracked when doing `git status` and the like. For files that are already tracked (added to git) it does nothing.

Comment: @Marius Notepad++ and then refreshed by Eclipse project by `f5` and then made the commit

Comment: @laalto `even before I made my first commit`? :)

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse and see if it helps. I noticed that on my laptop, Eclipse is caching stuff way too much, for example, if I create new xml file with LinearLayout, delete it, then create it again with same filename, but with RelativeLayout, the file created is the old deleted file with LinearLayout.

Comment: @Marius Yeah I have encountered that issue, too. Could it be an encoding issue? Change the encoding of gitignore to `ANSI`? How do I get rid of these unwanted files now that they are out there?

Comment: @LittleChild that was suggested in link I provided earlier.

Comment: @Marius how about getting rid of the file?