# Undo git rm -r --cached

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` file wasn't working, so I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working).

And now I have bunch of files that I need to commit, in order to proceed.
I made a mistake and committed those, because I couldn't find a way to get rid of those.

Is there any way that I can revert all these actions? I can't do `reset` cause I now I get error:
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout`.

Stupid stupid mistake, and I can find solution for this.

Comment: why don't you do a git checkout .?

Comment: I already committed those changes, so after rm -r cached, I did git add, and then commit. Now I can't delete that commit, because of that error.

Comment: git reset HEAD --soft  ?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you've run only `git rm -r --cached`, try doing a `git reset HEAD .` from within your repo root.

If you did a `git commit -m "msg"` after doing a `git rm -r --cached`, i.e., you committed the changes, then do `git reset HEAD~1` to [undo your last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1860929).

Comment: I can't, I'm getting message from above, on git checkout, git reset, whatever I try.

Comment: @Ned Can you update your question with the exact command you ran, and complete error message you get? I tried the scenario you are telling, and it works for me, so there might be something different in your commands.

Comment: Actually no, I had to clone my project into another folder, and start from scratch. It must be that I mess something with those files,but now sure what. However, your answer is valid, and it should work for other cases, mine was probably different for some other reason, and I will accept your answer so that it can help other guys. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case somebody runs into this issue, the solution by @mu無 works since it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Git works based on file caching so if you removed everything from the cache you can just reverse the whole process by executing .This will add back the files that were being tracked and tell which ones have been modified since the last commit .

```
> git add .
```

Comment: this didn't re-track my untracked file

Comment: mu 無's answer is the best answer because it completely removes the cached files from history. Please ignore this answer, you might also want to add a new question to your issue.

Comment: I had pushed some properties files to git, then later i wanted to add it to `.gitignore`. So, i added it and issued `git rm -r --cached .` . I ran `git status` it showed it deleted other files along with my `prop` files. But then i ssued `git add . ` it only staged deletion of `prop` files.

Comment: Plus one for the `git add`, I got the info `hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.` I did it and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

If you want git to make git "retrack" your files, that once where removed by **.gitignore** or by

```
git rm --cached
```

you can do it so by using:

```
git add -f <files>
```

After that if you want to remove files from the staged area you can use:

```
git restore --staged <files>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to revert it for only a particular file you can do 
`git restore --staged <file>`

Answer (score 1):

Running `git checkout HEAD path/to/file` will not work if the file is removed from the cache.

What worked for me is to move to a new branch by running the command:

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```