# Files are in conflict despite gitignore should ignore them

Tags: git

I have some files in conflict, despite `.gitignore` should ignore them. If I try to update the solution I get `Unmerged path`.

`git status` brings the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   abc_Library.userprefs
    deleted by us:   abc_Library/bin/Debug/abc_Library.dll
    deleted by us:   abc_Library/bin/Debug/abc_Library.dll.mdb
    deleted by us:   abc_Library/obj/Debug/abc_Library.dll

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I already defined the following `.gitignore`

```
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
*.userprefs
.DS_Store
```

As I can remember I already have [fixed the untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/426227). Can it be that a team member doesn't have the `gitignore` file and added the not needed files again? Or should I fix the untracked files again?

**Edit:**

Now I used

`git rm --cached abc_Library/obj/Debug/abc_Library.dll`

and the files don't appear as conflict anymore.

Comment: *Can it be that a team member doesn't have the `.gitignore` file* [...]? Is the `.gitignore` file itself under version control?

Comment: I only have added the file to my computer. How can I verify if it is under version control?

Comment: Try running, for instance, `git ls-tree --name-only origin/master -- .gitignore`.

Comment: If a file is being tracked already, then putting it in `.gitignore` alone will have no effect. It will still be tracked, checked out, merged, etc. If you're attempting to use `.gitignore` to get around valid merge conflicts, then you're doing something quite ugly (dangerous, wrong, scary, ill-advised, ...).

Comment: @Jubobs: When I run this command I get `.gitignore` as result. So it's being tracked?

Comment: @twalberg: I know and therefore you can delete the index and add the files again like in the linked SO answer. I'm not using `.gitignore` to get around merging conflicts. The files can be regenerated all the time but they differ because of different plattforms. I don't need these files in GIT. I want to get rid of these tracked files.

Comment: @testing Yes;it means it's being tracked.

Comment: @Jubobs: Removing the files as stated in my edited question seems to work. I hope it is now properly removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excerpt from the documentation of [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected.

When you add file names, paths or patterns to `.gitignore` you should remove the affected files from your repository:

```
git rm --cached abc_Library.userprefs
```

The option `--cached` asks `git` to remove the file only from the index, preparing this way the removal from repository on the next commit. The file from the working tree, modified or not, is not affected in any way.