# .gitignore not working with fresh repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got a brand new git repo which I've just checked out. I've then made an update to my `.gitignore` with the following line:

```
wp-config.php
```

My `git status` now reads:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

I add and commit this file (locally). I then update the `wp-config.php` file.

However, now, when I run `git status` I get the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   wp-config.php
```

I've gone through this [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working)
but the points made don't seem to be applicable as I'm using a completely fresh repo.

Any further suggestions?

Surely I don't have to commit it to the remote ('origin/master') to ignore it locally?

Comment: Did you by any chance, forced adding the file (with `git add -f wp-config.php`), because that will override the `.gitignore`.

Comment: This is one of the most recurring question about gitignore on Stack Overflow. Git will not ignore files that are already being tracked; you need to stop tracking them first.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like git is already tracking that file, so `.gitignore` is not working.

You can just stop `git` from tracking it with:

```
git rm --cached wp-config.php
```

After that you shouldn't see `wp-config.php` in the `git status` output.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is already being tracked by git, you need to remove it after you add it to the .gitignore. This will prevent it from being tracked further:

`git rm --cached wp-config.php`