# On git, how would I push changes to my deployed repo ignoring a specific folder that has already been pushed to my origin repo?

Tags: git, github, deployment

Initially I thought that a folder that shouldn't be tracked by git was included in my .gitignore file. However, for what ever the reason - it seems that this folder wasn't ignored.

Since then, I have made some changes and commits which have been pushed to my origin repo (including the folder I wish to have excluded). I recently 'untracked' the folder and pushed to the origin repo, which removed the folder altogether from the origin. This is fine but I'm now afraid that a push to my deploy server would delete this folder in the same way. How do I prevent this folder on my deploy server from being touched at all no matter of the commits made to it?

In a nutshell:
    - Origin repo is up-to date with latest commits. Has removed 'folder1' due to untracking 'folder1' on my local machine.
    - Deploy 'repo' is not yet up-to-date. Need 'folder1' to remain untouched after pushing.

Apologies if this has already been covered elsewhere, I couldn't find clarity on my exact scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You need to "reset" your git, so the .gitignore works well. Follow the first answer [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working) in order to make your .gitignore working.

Just don't forget to restore your "floder1" on your remote before, then .gitignore should do the trick.