# Why is my .gitignore file ignored?

Tags: git

I've read all the posts I can find here regarding my topic, but still can't seem to figure out why my `.gitignore` file is totally ignored.

My main repository folder is MediaStore. Inside it I have a VS project, it is committed. Now I create a file, test.txt in this MediaStore folder, it's not added, so not tracked. I also create a `.gitignore` file in the very same folder. It looks like this:

```
test.txt
MediaStore2/obj/
```

Still, when executing `git status` from within this folder, both the test.txt and the obj folder are listed as untracked. Why?

(Im working under Windows 7; posh-git and notepad for editing the file)

Comment: Did you add the .gitignore file to the staging area (at least)?

Comment: @Makoto that shouldn't be necessary I think

Comment: Can you add the output of `git status` to the question?

Comment: I think you need to commit the `.gitignore` file, then to use it.

Comment: Now Ive tried both with .gitignore staged and commited. Still no exclution.

Comment: Found this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/151344 Maybe interesting?

Comment: Sorry I dont yet have enough reputation to be allowed to post an image. Though it says: "Untracked files:" and then my supposed to be ignored file and folder are listed.

Comment: @MattiasCarleson It is better to copy the text only. However, I bet this can be an encoding issue like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451916/711006. Try to look at your `.gitignore` in a hex-editor.