# .gitignore not being recursively applied

Tags: git, gitignore

**End Goal:**
Have git recursively ignore files of type `*.abc`

**Problem:**
Git

**Description:**

I have the following line in my `gitignore` top level file located at `/home/alma/project-origin/.gitignore`.

```
/**/*.abc
```

I issue the following commands and get the following output

```
cd /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject
touch alma-wade.abc
git status .
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        alma-wade.abc

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

to trouble shoot I create a `.gitignore` file in that folder and run it again

```
cd /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject
touch alma-wade.abc
echo "*.abc" >> .gitignore
git status .
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        modified: .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I removed the .gitignore local file (`rm /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/.gitignore`) and started trouble shooting

**(A) Removing from cached**

[Source](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2012/11/18/gitignore-not-working-fixed/)

```
cd /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject
git rm -r --cached .
git commit -m "..."
git push origin master
#Successful push
git add .
git status .
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        alma-wade.abc

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**(B) Checking file encoding**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401387/git-add-adding-ignored-files)

```
file -bi /home/alma/project-origin/.gitignore
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

**(C) Checking for trailing spaces**

opened `/home/alma/project-origin/.gitignore` in vim and issued the command `:set list` and conducted a visual inspection

**(D) Using git check-ignore -v**

```
git check-ignore -v --no-index /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
#no output
echo "*.abc" >> .gitignore
git check-ignore -v --no-index /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
/home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/.gitignore:1:*.abc       /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
rm .gitignore
```

**(E) Using git check-ignore -v from top level directory**

This is the closest I have come to resolving this issue

```
cd /home/alma/project-origin/
echo "/**/*.abc" >> .gitignore
cd /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/
git check-ignore -v --no-index /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
#No output
cd /home/alma/project-origin/
git check-ignore -v --no-index /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
/home/alma/project-origin.gitignore:1:/**/*.abc       /home/alma/project-origin/top-secret/subject/alma-wade.abc
```

The top level `.gitignore` rule is applied when I do the check from the top level folder, but not when I am in a sub folder. I am at my wits end. The only thing I can think of is that this has something to do with the file system (cifs mounted). Could someone please help.

Comment: Do you have nested repositories? I.e., is there another `.git/` directory in `top-secret/` or `top-secret/subject/`?

Comment: @Chris yes in `top-secret` there is one (I don't recall intentionally making it)

Comment: @Chris is this as simple as just deleting one of the `git` folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested Git repositories, a `.gitignore` in an "outer" repository will not affect "inner" repositories:

```sh
mkdir outer && cd outer
git init
echo '/**/*.txt/' > .gitignore
touch foo.txt
git status
# Untracked file '.gitignore'
# No mention of 'foo.txt'

mkdir inner && cd inner
git init
touch foo.txt
git status
# Untracked file 'foo.txt'
```

Since you have an inner repository that you do not appear to have created deliberately I recommend removing its `.git/` directory (after making whatever backup you deem appropriate). This will make that directory's contents subject to the outer repository and the `.gitignore` should now take effect.

You will probably want to commit the files in the inner directory to the outer repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore every occurrence of files ending `.abc` then you just want: `*.abc` - `**` is mostly useful for matches which include subdirectory names in the match.

See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore for some examples on the `**` syntax (and other globs).

For example:

```
$ git init test
$ cd test
$ mkdir -p 1/2
$ touch foo.txt 1/bar.txt 1/2/baz.txt
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

1/
foo.txt

$ echo "*.txt" >.gitignore
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.gitignore
```

Comment: Are you saying that `*.abc` is equal to `/**/*.abc`? My understanding is that the former is **not** recursive

Comment: Yep - have added an example to the answer.