# Rails: .gitignore still tracking my database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have like 4 guys in my team and they constantly have to change the socket of the database because they have different paths for it, well it is becoming annoying, I tried to add database.yml to the .gitignore:

```
/config/database.yml
```

But for some weird reason when I edit the file and make a `git status`it still is being tracked!! can someone tell me what could be?

Comment: Once you added that file into repo, you need to do `git rm FILEPATH`.

Comment: You can run this command`git rm -r --cached <file>`

Comment: more of `git` thing than `rails`

Comment: you proably added it to your git repo in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo config/database.yml >> .gitignore
$ mv config/database.yml config/database.yml.example
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "put database.yml to .gitignore and and rename"
$ cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
```

Comment: Still need to tell git to remove it from the existing repo, eg the rm with -cached.

Comment: What I've forgot in the description is the `$ git add .`. To double check I've tried it again and it worked.