# .gitignore - Ignoring directory and file is not working

Tags: git, file, directory, gitignore, subdirectory

I follow these steps to ignore some directory in my Git :

1. I've create a .gitignore file (outside my .git directory)
2. I've add my ignored directories and files
3. I've add my .gitignore file onto my git index by "git add .gitignore"

But when I check my status, git always want to add directories and files I want to ignore...

[image: My .git and .gitignore location]

My .git and .gitignore location

[image: The file and directories I'd like to ignore]

The file and directories I'd like to ignore, but which are not ignored by git

Can you help me to resolve this problem please ?

Comment: drop the trailing `/` and the wildcards. also what is that first line: `!.gitignore`??

Comment: This Might Work:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/3319141:

Comment: @Vogel612 !.gitignore is apparently to "don't ignore" the file.

Comment: @BabulPrabhakar , I've tried "git rm -r --cached .", but still, it won't work.

Comment: @Tofuw As @Vogel612 already stated: You have to remove the `/` at the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you all, for your help. I've tried all your methods, it didn't work because I had already added and commited all my files before creating the .gitignore file. To solve my problem I just had to erase and do a git init again.