# How to handle Windows and OS X users using Android Studio on a Git Repo

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I've been developing our senior project Android App on Android Studio for OS X and the only other person that has been pulling/committing code is also on OS X. Today one of our partners pulled then opened Android Studio and then committed the changes, and it caused Android Studio to be unable to build the project and Gradle was also missing, so I had to roll back to a previous commit.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening so that the Windows users can work on the app with us OS X users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do is start my projects off with a good `.gitignore` file that covers all the ignorable files that are platform-specific as well as build products that don't need to be tracked. A quick search online will reveal many viable gitignore files that you can reference.

However, when you've already added files to a project and you want to ignore them henceforth, it's not as simple as modifying the `.gitignore` - there are some additional steps.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working) shows what I'm talking about.

Here are the steps copied from that top answer:

```
# update your .gitignore before running these...
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```