# When should I use rm, git rm, git rm --cached, git add

Tags: git

I am learning git, but I am confused by different ways of staging and committing files. To wrap my head around this I’m using a metaphor of directories: working directory, staging directory, commit directory.

- If I `rm` a file from my working directory, it only removes it *only* from my working directory. It that correct?
- If I `git rm` a file from my working directory, it removes it from all
  three directories. Correct?
- If I `git rm --cached` a file, it is removes the file from my staged
  and commit directories, but leave it in my working directory?
- If I have updated, added, and deleted files from my working
  directory, and do `git add .`, then `git status` shows staged files that have
  been added, deleted, and updated. What happens when I commit? Are the
  deleted files removed from the Commit directory? If I roll back to
  that commit later, will those deleted files reappear?

Any help to better understand these concepts would be appreciated -thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Tweak your understanding of the staging area (also known as the index or cache) and the `--cached` option. The [documentation for `git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) states

> ```
> --cached
> ```
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Running down your list gives

- `rm file` — remove file from the work directory only
- `git rm` — remove file from the work directory and from the staging area, but not yet part of the history (repository, “commit directory”)
- `git rm --cached` — remove from staging area but neither the work directory nor the history
- `git add .` in the presence of modifications, new files, and deleted files — git will record the modifications and new unignored files in the cache. ([`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) will behave differently with certain options.)

The `--cached` option to various git commands causes them to operate on the index or at least with respect to the index.

`git add` and `git rm` take changes from the work directory to the index or cache. Think of these commands as building up your next commit a piece at a time.

After you are happy with what’s in the index, move changes from the index to the repository with `git commit`.

Most of the time, what you want is the simple sequence `git rm file` followed by `git commit` to stop tracking *file* at the current point in your history.