# File name is too long: how to remove?

Tags: git

```
git status
```

shows following message:

```
lit/1252-a-comparison-between-neural-networks-and-other-statistical-techniques-for-modeling-the-relationship-between-tobacco-and-alcohol-and-cancer.pdf: File name too long
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean.
```

This file was deleted, which I can confirm with a following command:

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

Output:

```
lit/1252-a-comparison-between-neural-networks-and-other-statistical-techniques-for-modeling-the-relationship-between-tobacco-and-alcohol-and-cancer.pdf
```

When I try to remove it with `git ls-files --deleted | xargs git rm` there is no effect, but I cannot commit changes to my repository until I remove this file.

I have also tried to use: `git config --system core.longpaths true` but without success.

I wonder how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried [git rm --cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279654/when-should-i-use-rm-git-rm-git-rm-cached-git-add) on this file?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: @MattSlonetsky Please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rm --cached` is the command you're looking for.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280207/5074609) gives more details on git's add/remove commands