# Not sure why but .gitignore isn't working

Tags: git

I have added `/build/` to my `.gitingore` but whenever I do build, `git` shows that my `build` folder is untracked. I have following folder hierarchy

```
~/workspace/ProjectName/ ➤ 617a838|mainline⚡
1361 ± : tree -La 1                                                                                                                                                                                                  [6d1h6m] ✭
.
├── .DS_Store
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── Config
├── build
├── build.xml
├── checkstyle.xml
├── configuration
├── src
└── tst

5 directories, 5 files

~/workspace/ProjectName/ ➤ 617a838|mainline⚡
1362 ± : git status                                                                                                                                                                                                  [6d1h7m] ✭
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        build

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Here is content of `.gitignore`

```
/build/
/eclipse-bin/
```

one thing that i did notice is that `.gitingore` is a hidden file. Does this even matter?

Comment: does removing the / on the left make a difference?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working

Comment: Your `git status` output indicates that `build` is a *file*, not a directory ("folder").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` is fine for exculding a folder named `build` directly besides the `.gitignore` file and all its contents.

That the file is hidden is by definition. All files on *nix systems that start with a dot are considered hidden files and this does not interrupt the least.

That your ignore is not working is simply due to the fact that `build` is not a folder, but a file. The `git status` output says this at least and that is why the ignore is not working. If `build` would be a folder with some trackable content inside, it would appear as `build/` in `git status` output, not as `build`.

If `build` actually is a symbolic link to another folder, that would also explain the situation, because a symbolic link *is* file that *links* to a folder, but is not a folder by itself. In that case you would need to exclude the file `build` instead of the folder `build`, or to be correct both, the file and the folder called `build`, as you can fix the type to be a folder by appending a slash as last character, but you cannot fix the type to be a file. So if this is your situation, change `/build/` to `/build` and the symbolic link will be ignored.