# How to stop tracking ignored file in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I committed files from `.idea` folder, then I created `.gitignore` file, and I wanted to stop tracking those files from `.idea` folder.
To do this, I wrote:

> git rm -r --cached .
>
> git add .

and committed changes. Everything was fine until Android Studio changed file `misc.xml`, by changing java language level, and I do not know why, but if I try to commit changes, I can still commit this file `misc.xml`, which is ignored and should not be tracking anymore. What can I do?

[image: Android Studio View]

Comment: Did you do git add --all before commiting?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/423980

Comment: @Darush yes, after I made this commend, I made a commit of these changes.

Comment: @mt0s I made edit in the question, I used these commands to stop tracking ignored files, but one day after this, when Studio changed misc.xml, it still wants to add this to commit, even if it is no longer tracked.

Comment: Hmm... What if you use this command : `git status --ignored`  to check if the file is ignored so we can be 100% sure you have added it correctly in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @mt0s That was it. This command did not show all files from .idea folder, only 2 of them, excluding "misc.xml". Then I did one more time commands "git rm -r --cached ." and "git add .", seems like previous command did not work or I broke something.

Comment: I guess it was just too stupid or lazy... https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @mt0s from comment, I executed command

```
git status --ignored
```

and it showed only two files from idea, excluding misc.xml:

[image: .gitignore status]

So I repeated the commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

and now it works, it deleted all files from .idea from tracking, and now when I change something in a file misc.xml, it do not goes to commit.
[image: Result of repeated commands]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am still able to see ignored files in commit. This is so annoying.

Comment: Perfect solution