# Why isn't my .gitignore file working when adding files?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm looking at switching to git (from Perforce).  I'm doing an initial add of files to my repository, but for some reason my `.gitignore` file isn't being used.  When verifying the files being added via `git status` I can see files listed that should be ignored.  I must be missing something very basic.

Here's a very simplified directory structure that I'm testing with:

```
d:/git/
    .git
    Test/
        test.suo
        bin/
            Debug/
                test.dll
    .gitignore
```

And here is the relevant part of my `.gitignore` file:

```
**/*.suo
**/[Bb]in/Debug
```

When adding the files I call:

```
git add Test
```

And then I verify the files that have been added:

```
git status
```

Which shows me:

```
new file:   Test/bin/Debug/test.dll
new file:   Test/test.suo
```

What am I missing?  Why are these files being included?

Comment: I think you can just write `*.suo` and `Debug/` in `.gitgnore`. +1 for your profile pic!

Comment: @juan That doesn't make a difference.  Those files are still added and `git status` shows the same output.

Comment: Did you remove the files from index or tree? If the files still staged, try `git reset HEAD <file>`. If you committed them, try `git rm --cached <file>` but be careful. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working) might help.

Comment: I haven't committed any data yet; the repository is empty.  I've made sure to call `git rm --cached .` to remove all the files from stage.

Comment: I don't *think* you're missing anything. I just created the same structure and git did what you're expecting it to do, that is, ignore the files. However, it also listed my `.gitignore` as an untracked file. This seems to suggest that git can't find/see your .gitignore file. Can you post the exact directory listing of your project folder? Can you reproduce this from scratch? Are any of the tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working) relevant? (Especially your editor if you're on Windows)

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks.  Your suggestion that it can't see the file got me down the right path.  I originally created the file via PowerShell by doing a `echo $null >> .gitignore` (since Windows is fussy about file names).  I'm not sure why, but creating the file that way seemed the be the culprit.  Creating the file differently (in Windows Explorer) solved the issue.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson I've posted an answer with more details on what went wrong for you. Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of PowerShell's `echo $null >> .gitignore` to create the file initially is the problem. This is because it creates not a completely empty file (no bytes at all), but a file with a UTF-16 little-endian Byte Order Mark ("BOM") at the beginning.

As noted in [the comments to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/502378/68807) this does not play nicely with tools like git, which generally expect BOM-less files, typically in UTF-8 encoding.

It seems like [it's actually quite hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom) to create an empty file like that with PowerShell.

Comment: Great follow up Matt, +1.  I initially did a `touch .gitignore` and then I realized, oh yeah, Windows.  Thanks!