# How not to push your changes

Tags: git, laravel

I have changes in my `.env` files and this include my database user name and password. I don't want to push (now and in the future) these changes because my colleagues are using different user/password and they will be affected if I do so - this is the current setup.

What am I gonna do so when I issue `git status`, **modified:   .env** will not appear anymore but I have to keep my changes?

Comment: Why don't you add .env file to .gitignore file?

Comment: `.env` shouldn't be in Git at all. It's `.gitignore`d [by default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/f4cba4f2b254456645036139129142df274a1ec1/.gitignore#L12).

Comment: @Skywalker how to do that? it seemed to have no effect

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @ceejayoz, i just said that's the current setup, I can't do anything about that.

Comment: If its already in .gitignore file, then it won't get pushed to git.

Comment: @Skywalker, regardless of the status that says "modified"? other files listed in my gitignore do not behave this way when I edit them.

Comment: That's weird. It shouldn't show that file in the list of modified files if the file is added in .gitignore file. Check again in the .gitignore file if you have added it correctly.

Comment: The gitignore has no effect on files already staged/commited. Remove the file from the repository.

Comment: ifeego's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working helped me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it's already tracked (most likely).

You can remove it from the repository but keep your local copy by issuing the following:

```
git rm .env --cached
```

The `--cached` flag leaves it on your local machine, free to do what you like with it. The `rm` command will remove it from the repository tracker, however.