# Ignoring node_modules using .gitignore

Tags: git, npm, node-modules

I started a project using npm, added a few dependencies and then initialized the repository usign `git init`.

I wanted the directory `node_modules` to be ignored by git, so I added it to the `.gitignore` file like so.

.gitignore

```
node_modules/
```

Of course because `node_modules` was added before `git init`, it is still recognized as a directory to track.

So I deleted it, used the following commands (as suggesed for similar problems)

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore should now work"
```

Then reinstalled the npm dependencies by using `npm install`

After this I expect to have the directory `node_modules` to be finally ignored.
Instead if I type `git status` I get

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    node_modules/
```

Why?

Comment: Is this exactly the sequence you used? I cannot reproduce this result.

Comment: @DanLowe yes, I have double and triple checked, but nothing, it doesn't work.This looks absurd to me.

Comment: I too couldn't reproduce this. Tried the following steps:
`git init;
echo "Myfile" > myfile;
mkdir node_modules && echo "module" > node_modules/module.txt;
git commit -m "init";
echo "node_modules" > .gitignore;
rm -rf node_modules/;
git rm -r --cached .;
git add .;
git commit -m ".gitignore should now work";
mkdir node_modules;
echo "module" > node_modules/mod.txt;
`. `git status` gives "On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean" after running these.

Comment: @bless just tried again doing the same you did, but still have `node_modules/` as untracked after `git status`

Comment: `git rm -r --cached .` was the solution for me. After running this command, `node_modules` from `.gitignore` worked well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working) there are many possible fixes for a `.gitignore` file not properly working.

In this case the problem is (was) that the `.gitignore` file's encoding was UNICODE instead of ASCII

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

- Remove node_modules from .gitignore and save it
- Delete node_modules (or move it somewhere outside from the project directory)
- Commit the changes (there will be a tons of deletion from node_modules) This step will remove the files from source control.
- Add **node_modules** to .gitignore again
- Commit gitignore
- Re-run **npm install** or restore the **node_modules** directory.

Comment: Still not working, this is ridicolous, looks like a very stupid problem

Comment: Worked for me. Be careful about .gitignore file path.

Comment: Neat! I cloned a repo and it had `node_modules` tracked but when I check the `.gitignore` it says its ignoring the `node_modules`. I think someone committed the `node_modules` and then added it to `.gitignore` in my case which isn't the ideal order of things for git.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add .gitignore to git too

`git add .gitignore`

Comment: when you do git add .
It automatically adds everthing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34542742)