# How to reduce Node.js app size (or build it)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I built a small Node.js app and I want to put it on GitHub but the problem is node_modules is so large. Is there is any way to build the app and make it small?

Comment: Typically you would *not* upload the content of `node_modules/` to version control, just the `package{,-lock}.json` files that allow you to install the correct dependencies in another environment. What you build would also not be included in version control, as that's generated not source code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how can I do it , is there any doc or video to follow ?

Comment: Do what? If you mean remove node_modules, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301829/3001761.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store you project on GitHub without node_modules you need to create a `.gitignore` in the root of your porject (beside the `package.json` file) and add node_modules entry to it.

The structure should look like this:

```
/project
  ...
  package.json
  .gitignore
  package-lock.json // should NOT be added to the gitignore
```

And `.gitignore` should look look like this

```
node_modules
```

After that you need to push this `.gitignore` file to the remote repo (in your case to the GitHub).

By doing this you tell git to not track files which are inside the node_modules folder.

After pulling your project from remote (from GitHub) you will be able to get your modules back by using `npm install` which will install your dependencies inside node_modules folder.