# Exclude file from tracking

Tags: git, github

1. In `.gitignore` I added `*.o`.
2. I switched to my second branch (using console)
3. I created `test.o` with `touch test.o`
4. I used `git pull`
5. When I use `git status` I can see, that `test.o` is untracked, and can be tracked.

I expected that git will totally ignore `test.o` and dont metion about tracking. I cant use `git add .` now, because it will track `test.o`.

Is there a possibility to tell git to totally ignore `test.o` file?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/294949

Comment: You had to commit the changes to gitignore file after step 1. Was that commit merged to the branch you switched to? Otherwise, within that other branch, it is not going to ignore that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> I switched to my second branch

Does the branch have `*.o` in its `.gitignore`? If no — *.o files are tracked in the branch.

Have you committed the change in `.gitignore`? Merge or cherry-pick the commit into the second branch to propagate the change to the second branch. Or just edit and commit `.gitignore` again.

Comment: Do I have to create `.gitignore` per each branch? I Thought that `.gitignore` in `master` branch is for every branches.

Comment: No, it's per branch. You may have global `~/.gitignore` and you have per-repository `.git/info/exclude` files but their disadvantage is they are not shared with commits/pushes.

Comment: So when I created `pc` branch and merged with `master` I have no `.gitignore` in `pc` branch?

Comment: Should have — it must be a part of merge.

Comment: No. I dont have. This is the proof: https://puu.sh/z3szT/9609df2f62.gif. First tab is `master`, and second `pc`.

Comment: After you've merged `master` into `pc` you should have `.gitignore` in `pc` branch. Unless you resolved conflicts by removing the file. I don't understand your video, there are too many windows and mouse movements, and I'm text-mode guy, command line user.

Comment: Well as you can notice, there are not conflicts and there is no `.gitignore` in `pc` after `merge`.