# How to change default secrets.yml file in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I accidentally uploaded my `secrets.yml` file to Github.  I changed my credentials and moved it to a new `secrets_final.yml` file that I've property setup in gitignore.  Problem now is unless I hardcode credentials, the environment variables don't seem to pull from this new file.

How do I change default secrets location?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to tell Rails that your file with secrets is in another file than in `config/secrets.yml`? 

But what was the reason to change filename from `secrets.yml` to `secrets_final.yml`? Why you can't use default file anymore?

Comment: @MaciejNędza For some reason even after I added it to gitignore, it still tracked the file.  You got me thinking though and I was able to find a way to make that stop.  Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get `gitignore` to stop tracking a file as when I added it to `gitignore` file, it still tracked file because it was cached. No need to change defaults `secrets.yml` - just remove cache and use same file.  Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/5551783