# git not ignoring node_modules folder

Tags: git

Currently git is not ignoring node_modules folder. I have tried below command:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

Output of above line:

> fatal: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files

When I run `git status` I get the following output:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        configs/
        node_modules/
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        routes/
        server.js

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I don't want to include my `node_modules/` folder the next time I run `git add .`. Currently it is adding all the files from `node_modules/` folder.

Comment: did you commit your gitgnore file?

Comment: loose the slash at the end of node_modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)

Comment: @karthick: I haven't committed anything till now. My current gitignore file has two lines only: node_modules
package-lock.json

Comment: @karthick, there is no need to commit the `.gitignore` for it to take effect. I'm not sure where this myth came from. (It is a _good idea_ to commit it so it becomes part of the repository. But not having it committed doesn't prevent it from working.)

Comment: @karthick, and if I'm understanding you correctly, the "slash at the end of node_modules" isn't in OP's `.gitignore`. It's the output from `git status`.

Comment: @Chris, that's good to know, I was always under the impression that gitignore needs to be committed inorder for it to work.

Comment: @HashmatAli, is your ignore file in the root of the directory and named `.gitignore` _exactly_ (note the leading `.`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *.gitignore* file in same directory where are node_modules

and put this inside

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```