# Cannot commit file that is NOT inside gitignore file

Tags: javascript, teamcity, webstorm, gitignore, code-inspection

I am trying to allow TeamCity do JavaScript code inspection by following this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/06/javascript-code-inspection-server-side/

The problem is that the first step tells me to Share Scope in WebStorm and then commit it to source control. I have .idea/* added to gitignore file but right underneath to NOT ignore .idea/scopes/* where the necessary `.idea/scopes/JavaScript.xml` lives.

So eventually it looks like this

```
.idea/*
!.idea/scopes/*
```

Even with this added to gitignore I still cannot commit my JavaScript.xml file. Has anyone came across this and knows how to fix/commit it?

It looks like the problem is with the !.idea/scopes/* bit because after running `git status --ignored` I can see `.idea/` on the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add -f .idea/scopes` did the job

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20555367)

Comment: I am the author and this fixed my problem. File appeared in 'Files to commit'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash before .idea

```
/.idea/*
!/.idea/scopes/*
```

Comment: Still nothing, I have even gone into project files tree and tried git>commit file but got a message that no changes are detected. Also git add is disabled.

Comment: you could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working