# git is not recognizing entries in my gitignore file

Tags: git

I followed directions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working) and I am still ending up with the same handful of files. Even if I specifically invoke `git -rm --cached those/files*`, when I call `git status` I still see those same files in under "Untracked files:"

Here is what my gitignore file looks like:

```
# Files that exceed 100MB #
###########################
./data/9-26-18/altrans/SkinSunExposedLowerleg.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/MuscleSkeletal.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/Thyroid.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/WholeBlood.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/NerveTibial.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/HeartLeftVentricle.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/Lung.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/AdiposeSubcutaneous.Altrans.bestPerLink
./data/9-26-18/altrans/ArteryTibial.Altrans.bestPerLink
```

How do I make it so that these files, along with any other files I enter into .gitignore which exceeds 100MB in the future, are not even untracked, but are ignored altogether?

Comment: Is .gitignore placed in the root of the project? Have you tried removing the leading './' from each entry? Refer to the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Damn, I think I just realized the problem: for some reason, gitignore will not pick up on files preceded with a dot. So I have to remove these dots for gitignore to work, apparently. If someone could tell me why that is, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not so much "preceded by a dot" as the fact that the file's name is `data/9-26/18/altrans/Thyroid.Altrans.bestPerLink`, for instance. The name is not `./data/9-26-18/altrans/Thyroid.Altrans.bestPerLink`. Except for the special case of slashless names or `*` or `**` matches, Git is not doing component-analysis of the names: the name is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in "ignore by size".  You could write a program that inspects files, and for those that exceed some size threshold, updates the `.gitignore`.  A very simple shell script version to find "large files" is:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -size +100M -print | cut -c3-
```

(the `cut -c3-` discards the leading `./` that this `find` prints).

You can run these names through `git check-ignore` to see if they are already ignored, and if not, add them to `.gitignore`:

```
[find expression as above] |
while read -r name; do
     git check-ignore -q "$name" || printf '%s\n' $name >> .gitignore
done
```

Note that this assumes the `.gitignore` file itself will not grow so large as to cause problems.  If it would, be sure to eliminate `.gitignore` as an ignored file even if `.gitignore` exceeds your size threshold, e.g.:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -name .gitignore -prune -o -size +$limit -print
```

where `$limit` is the size threshold (100M for 100 megabytes, 10k for 10 kbytes, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured out the problem I had specifically and the code I ended up using was `find ./* -size +100M | cut -c 2-|  cat >> .gitignore` but this is definitely informative.