# adding all git history to a project whose history was not copied

Tags: git

I have the actual situation:

There is a project in which I have been working. It is git controlled. 
Another person copied the project but *did not copy* the .git folder and the .gitignore and .gitattributes files.

After that he made an interesting modification that I would like to integrate into the project.

My original question was going to be: How can I put all the original history to this last version of the project, but I think I have solved it, it is rather simple: I copied the .git and .gitignore .gitattribute files to the project and it immediately has the project git controlled (and of course I still need to commit the changes)

All nice and good except one thing that is bugging me. Now among the things I have to commit there is the  "add .gitignore file".

Does that mean that this was lost from the previous commits???

Comment: I would like to ask you to elaborate the "add .ignore file" thing. What is it, exactly?

Comment: adding the .gitignore file to a commit

Comment: Likely you need to check your previous git state. I would suggest to use `git worktree` functionality  (use a separate folder for the project with a chosen git state) or simply run `gitk --all` and view what files and with what content exist in the last committed version.

Perhaps you never committed `.gitignore` file in that folder or something like that.

Comment: @KansaiRobot did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do a `git add .` then commit all changes as you would normally do. Then reapply your .gitignore as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/1456927) to be on the safe side.

```
git add .
git commit -m "added new feature" 
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Make sure to commit your changes before doing the `git rm -r --cached .` or you will loose them.