# Git remove ignored files after commit

Tags: git

I have the following lines in my `gitignore` file:

```
!/assets/path-one/**/*.*
!/assets/path-two/**/*.*
!/assets/path-three/**/*.*
```

I pushed the changes, and all the files are included in the commit. What I want is to remove the `!` and remove all the files from the commit, how can I do this?

```
/assets/path-one/**/*.*
/assets/path-two/**/*.*
/assets/path-three/**/*.*
```

When I update the file, I see only the changes in the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive it in following setps

1. You need to remove the folders (Keep a backup of the folders if you want the contents)
2. update the gitignore by removing (`!`), add and commit the changes
3. Replace the backup if you need

Comment: 2. update the gitignore by removing (!) and *add* and commit the changes ;)

Answer (score 1):

First commit your changes and Try removing cache:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m "fixed untracked files"`
```

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/8866182.

Comment: This will make the whole project to be commited again, no?

Comment: yes,that's why I recommended you to commit all your changes before losing control on all changed files!