# Unable to git-ignore .env file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, git, gitignore

I have added .env name in ignorance file but it's not working. Please guide me.

My git-ignore:

```
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

bootstrap/compiled.php, 
app/storage/, 

public/storage, 
public/hot, 
storage/*, 
storage/*.key, 
.env.*.php, 
.env.php, 
.env, 
Homestead.yaml, 
Homestead.json
```

My git-ignore.save:

```
public/storage, 
public/hot, 
storage/*.key, 
storage/upload, 
storage/exports, 
storage/files/* , 
.env.*.php, 
.env.php, 
.env, 
Homestead.yaml, 
Homestead.json, 
storage/uploads, 
ven
```

Comment: If the file you are trying to ignore is already part of your repository, then just adding it to `.gitignore` won't work.  You have to `git rm --cached` the file first.

Comment: What is the name and file path of your "ignore" file? Note git-ignore looks wrong. And have you tried https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore ? Finally your file looks garbled. Please mark as code (select and click{} )

Comment: File name is .gitignore and file is existed in root.

Comment: Just put it like: `.env` in root's `.gitingnore` file

Comment: commas in gitignore?

Answer (score 4):

Your file is not being ignored because you previously told git to follow the file with `git add`, delete the file using `git rm -f .env`, and push the deletion, so it's fully ignored

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

> Make sure your git ignore file name is ".gitignore"
>
> First delete .env file and put .env in your .gitignore file then push
>   to your git repository
>
> After pushed to your repository then add .env file to your project
>   directory.
>
> It will solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your .env file is not getting ignored even after adding in .ignore than run below command in your terminal.

> git update-index --assume-unchanged .env

And if you feel later that you want to make some changes again in the .env file then run below command:

> git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .env

NOTE: In case of any other file replace .env with that filename(along with proper path)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that always works for me

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

This is from stackoverflow 
[.gitignore is ignored by Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-ignored-by-git)

Answer (score 0):

In your gitignore file, add an asterisk in front of the .env: *.env