# gitignore doesn't ignore untracked file

Tags: git, gitignore

Need to setup gitignore for upcoming project, current testing however shows it doesn't actually ignore the untracked file.

eBGTest being my git repo, the file I'm trying to ignore is eBGTest/test

eBGTest/.gitignore

```
/test/
.test
test
test
test
test
/test
./test
eBGTest/test
test.test
```

Edit (git status output):
Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    .gitignore
    test
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

It's not being tracked by git as you can see above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: It's not, this case it's untracked but still doesn't get ignored

Comment: Is `test` a file or a directory? If it's a directory, is there anything inside it? Speficially another `.git/` directory?

Comment: It's a file, not a directory

Comment: And it's in the root directory, alongside your `.gitignore`?

Comment: Yep, created within the exact same directory

Comment: And your `.gitignore` is named exactly that, just `.gitignore` without any file extension?

Comment: Yeah it is, .gitignore with no extension

Comment: What operating system are you on? What encoding and line endings does `.gitignore` have?

Comment: This sounds like the case where the `.gitignore` file's contents are encoded in UTF-16 (Windows editors do this to you).

Comment: It's possible, I'm using vi editor on git bash

Comment: So I just did some more testing, it works perfectly fine in other repos with the exact files, just not this one.

Comment: Please look through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11451535/354577).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add like this

```
  .test #or /test/
```

OR see this sites
[Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

OR
[gitignore](https://www.gitignore.io/)

OR
[tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)

Comment: Tried .test and /test/, no change.

Comment: If you are just testing and its new project follow this steps delete the hidden folder in you project folder ``` .git ``` then add .gitignore file and run this command ``` git init  && git commit -m "initial " ```

Comment: Tried that, now nothing in tracked but the test file still appears in untracked.

Answer (score -4):

Make `git add .gitignore; git commit -m 'First commit - gitignore'`

For the .gitignore to ignore the files, you must first commit, and then the changes will be applied.

After this, the `test` file will be ignored.

Comment: Committed .gitignore, results are the same, test is not ignored.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test

Comment: This is incorrect. `.gitignore` does not need to be committed to work (though it _should_ be; local-only ignores should go into `.git/info/exclude` instead).