# .gitignore is being ignored by git gui

Tags: git, gitignore, git-gui

I'm using git gui. Trying to exclude some files (*.dll, *.pdb - for example from my **Unstaged Changes** list).
I have a .gitignore file (UTF-8), located at the same folder as the .git folder.
For the test case, I'm trying to remove *.dll files(I have these kind of files already committed in the past - I just don't want them to appear in the Unstaged Changes, after making a new build).
Here is my .gitignore file content:

```
    # See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

    # compiled output
    /dist
    /tmp
    /out-tsc
    # Only exists if Bazel was run
    /bazel-out

    # dependencies
    /node_modules

    # profiling files
    chrome-profiler-events*.json
    speed-measure-plugin*.json

    # IDEs and editors
    /.idea
    .project
    .classpath
    .c9/
    *.launch
    .settings/
    *.sublime-workspace

    # IDE - VSCode
    .vscode/*
    !.vscode/settings.json
    !.vscode/tasks.json
    !.vscode/launch.json
    !.vscode/extensions.json
    .history/*

    # misc
    /.sass-cache
    /connect.lock
    /coverage
    /libpeerconnection.log
    npm-debug.log
    yarn-error.log
    testem.log
    /typings

    # System Files
    .DS_Store
    Thumbs.db


    #server side
    *.dll
    *.pdb
    *.suo
    *.cache
    *.ide-wal
    *.out
```

What Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: "I'm trying to remove *.dll files(I have these files already committed in the past)" You understand that `.gitignore` does not help you in any way to ignore files you have already committed?

Comment: Have you read http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ ?

Comment: @matt - Yes !  i'm aware of it - I'm trying to get rid of these  files in my current commits

Comment: That is what `git rm` is for.

Comment: Wow, Thanks - what a typo !

Answer (score 0):

I was missing important step in order to make the .gitignore active with files which were already tracked. I found the solution in this stackoverflow question:
[.gitignore is ignored by Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-ignored-by-git)

by executing these commands, I solved the problem (after making sure all my files are committed):
git rm -r --cached
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"

- This made my files untracked - more than I needed - now I need to figure out how to make them controlled again