# How to add podfile.lock and .DS_store to .gitignore

Tags: swift, xcode, git, gitignore

I have added in .gitignore like this:

```
Pods/
MyStarhub.xcworkspace/
*/xcuserdata/
DerivedData/*
Podfile.lock
*.DS_Store
*.icloud
```

But git keeps tracking [.Ds_Store Podfile.lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqOl.png) for some reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451731/6791677

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because git is still tracking the files you pushed previously. Try:

```
git rm --cached .DS_Store
git rm --cached Podfile.lock
```

Or simply delete the files, commit and push

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But when I try it, these 2 files appeared in the "Staged Files" section with the red minus icon.
So I still have to commit them right?

Comment: Yeah, the minus indicates that you are removing them from tracking.