# .gitignore not ignoring files correctly

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have a TeX project. I want to ignore some file extensions which I have added in the .gitignore file, but they are still shown as untracked files in `git status`. How to make git not track these files? A figure is added showing the VS code workspace along with the staged area `git ls-files` and output of `git status`. You can see the message about the same files being untracked in color red.

[image]

Comment: May you share the `.gitignore` file contents and the commands (with their output) as text?

Comment: [Text, not screenshots, please.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it. It works if I create the `.gitignore` using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu). It does not work if created through Windows 10 VS Code editor. A similar thing is also mentioned in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451916/21205111). It also worked when I created the `.gitignore` file using echo in Git Bash which is a Linux environment. Strange indeed! It probably has something to do with the carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF).

Comment: I just tested and having the file with CRLF format did **not** break it. You have already solved it but I would have loved to see what `git check-ignore` had to say about those files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have spaces before your patterns in the file.  This space is treated as part of the pattern, not an indentation.

It'd be easier to tell this if you included text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: There is no space