# Using SASS with Git, what files do I ignore and how?

Tags: css, git, sass

I've got a framework in my `/project` directory, where I have multiple `.sass-cache` folders.

For example, I could have this

```
/project/-/-/one/.sass-cache
```

And this

```
/project/-/-/two/.sass-cache
```

And this

```
/project/three/.sass-cache
```

And I want to add all of the to .gitignore.
I've tried this:

```
# Sass #
###########
*.sass-cache*
```

But it fails and git still picks up changes in them. How do I properly add my `.sass-cache` folders to my `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With `.gitignore`, a single asterisk is only a wildcard for a specific directory. If your git version is up-to-date, you should be able to use the double asterisk to indicate any level of subdirectories.

Single asterisk will only match files for that directories depth

```
foo/*/* == foo/bar/file.xyz
foo/*/* != foo/bar/dir/file.xyz
foo/*/* != foo/file.xyz
```

Two asterisks matches any directory depth

```
foo/** == foo/bar/file.xyz
foo/** == foo/bar/dir/file.xyz
foo/** == foo/file.xyz
```

For your case, I would suggest trying the following...

```
**/.sass-cache
**/.sass-cache/*
```

Lastly, I don't know if it would work, but you might also try...

```
**.sass-cache**
```

On this last one, I'm not sure how the double-asterisk would get interpreted. The two lines above this should work fine though.

Comment: In case this still don't work, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working

Comment: `**.sass-cache**` worked for me in my perfect in my WordPress theme

Answer (score 20):

I just use

```
.sass-cache
.sass-cache/*
```

And that seems to work fine.

Comment: I should add that my sass-cache directories are several directories deep compared to where the git ignore file is.

Comment: That sounds like it should work for me, but it doesn't look like it.

Isn't there some kind of cached git tree that I need to clear to make it forget changes it might have already noticed in those directories?

Comment: Dang, I'm far from a git expert, but I have had success with the above config in my git ignore file. Would the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810233/git-ignores-content-of-gitignore help?

Comment: This should be enough, but remember that if this directory has already been tracked, you'll need to untrack that directory. See if it's tracked with `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`. Untrack it with `git rm -r --cached ./.sass-cache`

Comment: Thanks for the untrack tip, that helped me.

Answer (score 4):

One more thing.You should add `**.css.map` in your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using

```
.sass-cache/
*.css.map
```

as especified in github's gitignore descriptions (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Sass.gitignore), it seems to work having .sass.cache files at whatever level in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who set up your workflow with npm install node-sass.

- Before you do git init do the following
- create .gitignore in root of your project
- the .gitignore file will be blank in your code editor
- in the .gitignore file type node_modules
- now all your dependencies won't be added to your repository
- now do your git init etc...

source.  traversy media video "Responsive Portfolio, SASS workflow setup"

Answer (score -2):

Hello for my own only work for this resource:

```
**/.sass-cache/*
```

Thats because whatever place we start compiling sass (from whatever root position inside proyect) it create a new **.sass-cache**

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?